# Can I get a value out of a path in a svg file with Javascript ? Or can I convert it into a xml and get it out of there?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg, snap.svg

I am creating a SVG file with Inkscape. In there i have a path (shown down in the code). I want to either get the inkscape:original-d or the d into my javascript file with something like getElementByID but nothing seems to work. Do you guys know if I can somehow import the data out of that SVG file? It also has a xml structure maybe that can help? Leave everything that could help in the comments thanks !

Btw. I am using Snap.svg as a libary to manipulate my SVG File maybe you guys know a way how I can solve the problem with that libary.

```
<path
         inkscape:original-d="m 110.36905,95.916669 v 52.160711 h 92.98214 v 40.06548"
         inkscape:path-effect="#path-effect821"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         id="L_PUF_AKL"
         d="m 110.36905,95.916669 c 0,11.243311 -0.0171,30.565001 -0.0389,52.160711 0,-3.5e-4 -4e-5,0.0393 -4e-5,0.0389 -0.006,0 0.0452,3e-5 0.039,2e-5 30.13329,0.0171 62.75026,0.0372 92.88868,0.0543 -0.0218,16.55036 -0.0388,31.35222 -0.0388,39.9722 0,0 0.13229,0 0.13229,0 0,0 0.13229,0 0.13229,0 0,-8.63617 -0.0171,-23.47747 -0.0389,-40.06548 0,5e-5 -1.3e-4,-0.0934 -1.3e-4,-0.0934 -0.001,0 -0.0917,5e-5 -0.0932,5e-5 -30.15147,0.0171 -62.78962,0.0372 -92.94323,0.0544 -0.0219,-21.57998 -0.0389,-40.88518 -0.0389,-52.121731 z"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;fill-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am try this code and it works.

`let test = document.getElementById('L_PUF_AKL');
console.log(test.getAttribute('inkscape:original-d'));`

Comment: When i try this I am getting this error message ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null```

Comment: Maybe your DOM not ready and you trying get attribute on not available object. You can set script under path object.

Comment: but i am not opening the svg file itself i am using snap.svg to load the svg file and then display it like this ```<svg id="LagerSvg", width="1500", height="750"></svg> ```

Comment: You need to show your javascript code every time, as your problem is probably there and not in your svg.